# How to update filtered Sharepoint list on power automate

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-list

Not sure if I am doing something wrong but I am trying to update a Sharepoint list automatically from a response from a form, so 1)the trigger is a form response, 2)I then store a form response in a variable, I filter the "get items' using the variable so that only the response remains and 3) I  loop through the filtered items and update them . The issues it that when I loop through the filtered items and update them, all the row in the list are updated with the response and not just the filtered ones

I  looped through the filtered items and updated them

Comment: Show us your flow. We’d take your word for it but something’s not right so you need to show us.